# Someone who has a wonderful talent in poetry

Tags: phrase-choice

Which one of the following sentences sounds more natural to you to describe someone who has a wonderful poetic talent:

> - He has a great / wonderful **poetic talent**.
> - He has a great / wonderful **poetic gift**.
> - He is very **talented in poetry**.

I had a research on the internet, but the only thing that I found was that these three bold parts can be used in these ways ([here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poetic%20talent%2Cpoetic%20gift%2Ctalented%20in%20poetry&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoetic%20talent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoetic%20gift%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalented%20in%20poetry%3B%2Cc0)), but I was not sure about the sentences' structures that they can be used.

Comment: Is the person a poet?

Comment: @TRomano No, he is not a poet, but he has a strong potential to be a poet. Suppose someone else is talking about him, who knows and understands poetries and even he / she's made some poetries himself / herself. This is the way he / she (as a poet or someone who understands poetries) is saying about him. :)

Comment: He has  a gift for poetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would most recommend the following sentence:

- He has a wonderful **talent for** poetry

> **talent** *noun*
>   **1.** a. A marked innate ability, as for artistic accomplishment:
>   *has a rare talent for music.*
>   <sub><sup>[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/talent)y</sup></sub>

- He is a **[talented](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/talented)** poet

This second one suggests that the person is a poet by profession, but in a suitable context, it could imply that they are naturally gifted.

The adjective *talented* can take the preposition *in*

- He is very **talented in** poetry

This construction isn't as common as the previous two though.

A fourth possibility is to say

- He has a **natural talent** (or **gift**)  for poetry

See [**Google Books Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=natural%20talent%20for%2Ca%20talent%20for%2Ctalented%20in%2Ca%20gift%20for%2Cgifted%20in&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnatural%20talent%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20talent%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalented%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20gift%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgifted%20in%3B%2Cc0) on how the expressions compare to one another.

Answer (score 0):

The third sentence sounds best to me, so I would choose:

> He is very talented in poetry.